# VS Express 2012 Desktop how to save user's input

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am very new to VS 2012 and I'm wondering how I can save what a user has inputted so that it's there when they re-open the program. Right now I just have 2 buttons that increase a label by 1 each time you press them and another label that divides one by the other into a per cent.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim k, d, r As Single
    k = Label2.Text + 1
    d = Label4.Text
    r = (d / k)
    Label2.Text = k
    Label6.Text = Format(r, "Percent")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim k, d, r As Single
    k = Label2.Text
    d = Label4.Text + 1
    r = (d / k)
    Label4.Text = d
    Label6.Text = Format(r, "Percent")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It your case you have to save your input to some external file, and on reopen program to read that file and to init your fiels (labels, textboxes ets)

Good tutorial about read write from-to files using vb [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets8p4.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use **Application Settings** to store the values.

Go to Project --> Properties --> Settings Tab.
Add entries for "Label2", "Label4", and "Label6", leaving the Type as String:

[image: Project Settings]

Now add code to the Load() and FormClosing() events of your Form to load and save the values to/from your Application Settings:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If My.Settings.Label2 <> "" Then
            Label2.Text = My.Settings.Label2
        End If
        If My.Settings.Label4 <> "" Then
            Label4.Text = My.Settings.Label4
        End If
        If My.Settings.Label6 <> "" Then
            Label6.Text = My.Settings.Label6
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim k, d, r As Single
        k = Label2.Text + 1
        d = Label4.Text
        r = (d / k)
        Label2.Text = k
        Label6.Text = Format(r, "Percent")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim k, d, r As Single
        k = Label2.Text
        d = Label4.Text + 1
        r = (d / k)
        Label4.Text = d
        Label6.Text = Format(r, "Percent")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        My.Settings.Label2 = Label2.Text
        My.Settings.Label4 = Label4.Text
        My.Settings.Label6 = Label6.Text
        My.Settings.Save()
    End Sub

End Class
```